# Reading non-ascii characters from a file in C

Tags: c, ascii

I have a file, `foo.txt`, which is just:

```
” ’

char x = fgetc(myfile);
```

When I use `fgetc` on the file, I get a constant value of `226` on both characters. Why is this? How can I fix this?

Here is my code:

```
FILE* f = fopen("./debate.txt", "rb");
int x = fgetc(f);
char y = (char)x;
```

Comment: A) What encoding. B) Show us more code, *especially* how you open the handle.

Comment: That doesn't seem right, they're different, are you sure the values are the same? How are you seeing these values? More code is needed.

Comment: `I get a constant value` how do you check that value? `on both characters.` on which characters?

Comment: @anastaciu I have been checking with my debugger. Moreover, when I print these values out, they are not matching.

Comment: `fgetc()` is not aware of "wide" characters, by the way. For non 8-bit encodings this won't work.

Comment: @tadman What can I do to read these characters?

Comment: Those "curly quotes" are not ASCII. They are Unicode 201D and 2019. This "text" is probably UTF-8 encoded (which would be E2 80 9D E2 80 99).

Comment: @user15200182 If you want to read wide characters, use `fgetwc`

Comment: @WilliamPursell But how do I print the wide character to the console?

Comment: @user15200182 `fputwc`

Answer (score 2):

For normal (portable) software, character encodings are a whole world of pain. The problems (and potential solutions) are:

**A) The text file may be in any random/"text editor defined" encoding.**

To deal with this there's 4 options:

- expect input in a specific encoding (e.g. UTF-8) and refuse to support anything else (and generate an error message if the data in the file isn't valid for the encoding you chose). This will annoy some users (e.g. where the national standard is something incompatible like CNS 11643 ).
- support many encodings, and let the user choose which encoding to expect (e.g. based on a command line argument). This is a little inconvenient for users and very painful for you.
- support many encodings, and try to auto-detect which encoding the file used. This is a little more convenient for users until it guesses wrong and becomes a major annoyance (and you can't reduce the chance of guessing the wrong encoding to zero).
- support many encodings, and let the user choose the encoding if they want, and auto-detect if the user didn't specify. This is the best possible option for users (and the worst possible option for software developers).

For these options I'd use the first (I would say "input file must be UTF-8", partly because UTF-8 has become very common and well supported, and partly because every other encoding is provably worse for technical reasons). Note that (based on your results) it's extremely likely that your input file is in UTF-8.

**B) Whatever the compiler uses for `char` is implementation defined (could be ASCII, could be EBDIC, could be anything else), and may be either signed or unsigned.**

In this case it's "very safe" (for portability) to assume ASCII. Assuming UTF-8 is the 2nd best choice but it creates problems with any code that does any maths (e.g. right shift, etc) on "possibly signed" `char` values.

**C) The `stdin`, `stdout`, `stderr` pipes are random/implementation defined too.**

This is similar to the previous problem, except that the best solution ("assume ASCII") is significantly harder (especially when you want to output error messages, etc that contain pieces of text from the input file). For this I'd be tempted to use ASCII as much as possible, but to cheat and output UTF-8 if I have to. If the OS (or shell) can't handle UTF-8 it'll create a mess, but most users would understand (and can work around it by piping your output to a file). The best alternative (for user output) is using a GUI and not using `stdout`, but that creates a large set of extra problems (and leads to a second large set of extra problems - internationalization for things like error messages, etc).

**D) Whatever the compiler assumes for `wchar` is random/implementation defined (maybe UTF-16, maybe UTF-32, maybe anything else; and it may even be an 8-bit encoding that isn't "wide" at all).**

The only sane choice here is to recognize that `wchar` is an unusable failure that should never (under any circumstances) be used for anything.

To be more specific, `wchar` is a historical mistake based on previous historical mistakes. Essentially, in the early days, Microsoft and Sun decided to adopt UCS-2 (an "all Unicode codepoints fit in 16 bits" assumption) which quickly became broken. To work around that problem Microsoft and Sun switched to UTF-16, but Microsoft was primarily running on little-endian machines and chose UTF-16LE and Sun (Java) was aiming for big-endian machines and chose UTF-16BE. The `wchar` extension was added to C in 1995 at the same time that companies (Microsoft, Sun) where doing everything wrong and weren't doing anything that is compatibility with each other; so `wchar` ended up being a "we don't know what the standard is so our standard is no standard at all" joke. For C (and C++) this was fixed in 2011 with the introduction of `char16_t` (UTF-16) and `char32_t` (UTF-32) in `<uchar.h>`, but adoption is slow (e.g. Microsoft is still too lazy to bother with C99).

Note that an additional part of the problem is that people want to assume that one `wchar` is one whole printable character, and that is almost never the case (e.g. even for UTF-32 where one `wchar` is one whole Unicode codepoint there are combining codepoints); and this ruins any benefit of any "wide char" implementation (even if your code is not portable at all and you know what `wchar` actually is).

The best solution (especially if you chose "expect that the input file is using UTF-8" to solve the first problem) is to use UTF-8 stored in `uint8_t` (so that nobody confuses it for whatever `char` is).

In that case; "converting the input from the file into your internal character encoding" can become "converting UTF-8 to UTF-8 by doing nothing"; and "converting your internal character encoding into whatever `stdout` wants" becomes "converting UTF-8 to ASCII (or UTF-8) by doing almost nothing (casting from `uint8_t` to `char`)". In other words, it can be extremely close to "use the same encoding for everything".